# Find rows number of a matrix that match with rows of another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, match

I have for example two matrix `mat2` and `mat1`. Where `mat2` is nested in `mat1`. I want to find out which rows of `mat1` are exact similar to `mat2`.

This is an example code

```
mat1 = matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),8,3)
mat2= matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1),4,3)
mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1
[5,]    0    1    0
[6,]    1    0    0
[7,]    1    1    1
[8,]    1    1    0
 mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1
```

Here 2nd, 3rd, 4th and  7th rows of `mat1` are similar to `mat2`. How can I find this through R code?

Comment: In the example you give, `mat2` is not nested anywhere in `mat1`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option that scans through `mat1` starting from row 1,  terminating the loop if it finds `mat2` in `mat1` & returning the row in `mat1` where `mat2` starts.

```
f <- function(mat1, mat2) {
    ret <- NA_integer_
    for (i in 0:(nrow(mat1)-nrow(mat2))) 
        if (all(mat1[(i+1):(nrow(mat2) + i), ] == mat2)) {
            ret <- i + 1
            break
        }
    return(ret)
}

f(mat1, mat2)
#[1] 2
```

PS. Very curious to see other options and benchmark comparisons.

---

Answer (score 2):

Update base R:

We could also use `match`:

```
identical_rows <- match(apply(mat1, 1, paste, collapse = ""), apply(mat2, 1, paste, collapse = ""))

which(identical_rows > 0)
```

Output:

```
[1] 2 3 4 7
```

Here is a tidyverse approach: We could pull the indices after a `semi_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mat1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  semi_join(mat2 %>% 
              as_tibble, by = join_by(V1, V2, V3)) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

output:

```
[1] 2 3 4 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asplit()` + `%in%`:

```r
which(asplit(mat1, 1) %in% asplit(mat2, 1))

# [1] 2 3 4 7
```